# Deleting a row from a Datatable if that row exists in another Datable

Tags: c#

I have two DataTables with the same columns:

`DataTable dt;`

`DataTable posTable;`

Sometimes they can have different numbers of row..

I want to delete a row from the table if it exists in another..

I tried using this code:

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Zip<DataRow, DataRow, DataRow>(posTable.AsEnumerable(), (DataRow modif, DataRow orig) =>
{
  if (orig.ItemArray.SequenceEqual<object>(modif.ItemArray))
  {
     modif.Delete();
  }
  return modif;
}).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

but it didn't work :( [it only deletes what's not exists in another] i tried turning it around but gives me errors.

Any code suggestion?

Comment: What does 'didn't work' mean? Did you get an exception? Is `Delete()` ever called, while stepping through your code?. Also: If you delete `modif`, why do you want to return it?

Comment: Second question: Do you want to delete the rows or does displaying rows which do not exist suffice?

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows from a database (which `DataRow.Delete` suggests but you need a `DataAdapter`) or do you just want to [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove(v=vs.100).aspx) them from the table?

Comment: Also and most important: what is a duplicate at all? If it has the same ID or all column values are the same?

Comment: @Serv : i thought the `modif.Delete()` will be deleted after the `dt.AcceptChanges();`.. is it a bad code? Can you suggest a better code? pls?? it would help :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: i want to delete a row if all of its  column values are the same

Comment: @BienvenidoOmosura: i guess you haven't still understood the difference. Do you want to delete them in database or remove them in the table?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i want to delete them in DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link also examples about Compare two tables

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/686406/How-To-Compare-and-delete-datatable-row-using-Csha

Or

I think this example is use for you..

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
dt1.Rows.Add("Apple");
dt1.Rows.Add("Banana");
dt1.Rows.Add("Orange");

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("Name");
dt2.Rows.Add("Apple");
dt2.Rows.Add("Banana");

List<DataRow> rows_to_remove = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
    {
        if (row1["Name"].ToString() == row2["Name"].ToString())
        {
            rows_to_remove.Add(row1);
        }
    }
}

foreach (DataRow row in rows_to_remove)
{
    dt1.Rows.Remove(row);
    dt1.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `SequenceEqual` but you have to use  [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `Delete`. The latter deletes them from database if you use a `DataAdapter`, the former removes them from the table.

Another approach is filtering with LINQ and using `CopyToDataTable` on the remaining rows:

```
var rows1 = dt.AsEnumerable();
var rows2 = posTable.AsEnumerable();
dt = rows1 
    .Where(r1 => !rows2.Any(r2 => r1.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(r2.ItemArray)))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

This keeps only non-duplicate rows because of the `!rows2.Any` in the `Where`-filter.